# Why does my pycharm code give "list index out of range" ? I'm following the youtuber

Tags: python, pycharm, face-recognition

I'm doing a face-recognition code, at first I followed the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sz25xxF_AVE&list=WL&index=10&t=2228s) done by Murtaza and it worked but when I tried to do it by my own I fell in that problem and couldn't solve it yet, Here is the code:

```
while True:
    success, img = webcam.read()
    imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
    imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    imgSLocs = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
    imgSEncodes = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, imgSLocs)

for encode, loc in zip(imgSEncodes, imgSLocs):
    compare = face_recognition.compare_faces(refEncodes, encode)
    faceDist = face_recognition.face_distance(refEncodes, encode)
    print(faceDist)
    matchindex = np.argmin(faceDist)
    print (matchindex)
    if compare[matchindex]:   # in this line the error starts <------------
        name = refImgNames[matchindex].upper()
        print(name)
```

What I expect is matchindex = 0 or 1 because I only have two images, but what happens is that `matchindex = np.argmin(faceDist)` has almost no effect on the code, shouldn't it give me the index of least value in these values?
Notes that might be useful: `faceDist` is a compound array that has probably 128 values inside index 0 and 128 values inside index 1.
I'm new at python codes so please consider the probability of basic mistakes.
here's the whole code if it can help:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import os

path = 'refrence images'
imgList = os.listdir(f'{path}')
refImgs = []
refImgNames = []
print(imgList)
for i in imgList:
    image = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{i}')
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    refImgs.append(image)


def imgEncoder(images):
    encodes = []
    for i in images:
        imgloc = face_recognition.face_locations(i)
        imgencode = face_recognition.face_encodings(i, imgloc)
        encodes.append(imgencode)
    return encodes


refEncodes = imgEncoder(refImgs)
print('encoding done Alhamdulillah')
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, img = webcam.read()
    imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
    imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    imgSLocs = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
    imgSEncodes = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, imgSLocs)

    for encode, loc in zip(imgSEncodes, imgSLocs):
        compare = face_recognition.compare_faces(refEncodes, encode)
        faceDist = face_recognition.face_distance(refEncodes, encode)
        print(faceDist)
        matchindex = np.argmin(faceDist)
        print (matchindex)
        if compare[matchindex]:   # in this line the error starts
            name = refImgNames[matchindex].upper()
            print(name)
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = loc
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1 * 4, x2 * 4, y2 * 4, x1 * 4
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0.255, 0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y2 - 35), (x2, y2), (255.255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(img, name, (x1 + 6, y2 - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1)
            cv2.imshow(1,img)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
    print('done')
```

[you can see on left panel that I only have 2 images (1.png, 2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdfc9.png)

Comment: Can you add what does `print (matchindex)` print out? And can you paste the actual error that is thrown (this is usually the most important part of a question on StackOverflow as it gives as the best input on what could be the error)?

Comment: You are making the assumption that the two lists `compare` and `faceDist` have the same length, since you compute `matchindex` on `faceDist` and read at position `matchindex` in `compare`.

Comment: Hmmm, it's rather a question of better understanding numpy's `ndarrays`, and how `argmin` works.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider to use deepface? You can do it with a few lines of code.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
DeepFace.stream(db_path = "C:/my_db")
```

Here, you should store your facial image database in my_db folder with .jpg or .png extensions. Stream function will access your web cam and run face recognition and facial attribute analysis (age, gender, emotion) in real time.